# pip install -u rosdep - No distributions at all found for rosdep

Tags: rosdep, pip, rospkg, rosinstall, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS community,

I am running a armhf ubuntu system.  I need to install rosdep an wstool.  The ROS website says use:

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep
sudo pip install -U wstool
```

When I try those commands I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking rosdep
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rosdep
No distributions at all found for rosdep
```

With rosdep and wstool names changed respectively.

When I go to the website "https://pypi.python.org/pypi"

I get a:

```
502 Bad Gateway
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
```

Is there a mirror or another way to install the ros python package tools (rosdep, wstool, rospkg, rosinstall, etc) for a non-standard ROS system?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60001/pip-install--u-rosdep---no-distributions-at-all-found-for-rosdep/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like the site is back up and working.

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1